# Hey Why Iam getting Unexpected token 'integer' error in trigger and below is my code. can anyone tell what mistake I did?

Tags: after-trigger

```
trigger StudentTriggers on Student__c (after insert, after update) {
   
    
    for(Student__c a: Trigger.New){
        if( a.College_name__c == 'DGVC'){
            a.Name = a.Student__c;
            a.Last_Name__c = a.Clone_Last_Name__c;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for the error you're getting, as you don't have the word `Integer` in your code-- it may be in a different compilation unit. However, you do have an error in your trigger. Records in `Trigger.new` are read-only in an `after` trigger, so you'd get a `System.FinalException` during your trigger's execution. Change the first line to:

```
trigger StudentTriggers on Student__c (before insert, before update) {
```

During a before trigger, changes to `Trigger.new` records will be committed to the database when the records are saved.